# How to test React-Admin without API or Backend

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am very new to React-Admin. I have successfully setup the project and it's working fine. One thing which I learned here is that we have to pass "Data Provider" to the "Admin" component and some resources. Basically I am using the default example from the React-Admin.

My issue is that I don't have any back-end or API. What I have is just a "json-data" which I am importing to my index.js. I don't know how I can use this dummy data to view a list of users. Below is my index.js file and the file frome where I am importing the dummy json data

```
// in src/admin/index.tsx
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
// import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { jsonData } from '../data/response';
import { UserList } from '../data/Users';

const dataProvider = JsonData;

console.log('data provider----', dataProvider);

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name='users' list={UserList} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Here is my dummy json data file.

```
export const jsonData = [
    {
        userId: 6,
        id: 51,
        title: 'soluta aliquam aperiam consequatur illo quis voluptas',
        body: 'sunt dolores aut doloribus\ndolore doloribus voluptates tempora et\ndoloremque et quo\ncum asperiores sit consectetur dolorem',
    },
    {
        userId: 6,
        id: 52,
        title: 'qui enim et consequuntur quia animi quis voluptate quibusdam',
        body: 'iusto est quibusdam fuga quas quaerat molestias\na enim ut sit accusamus enim\ntemporibus iusto accusantium provident architecto\nsoluta esse reprehenderit qui laborum',
    },
    {
        userId: 6,
        id: 53,
        title: 'ut quo aut ducimus alias',
        body: 'minima harum praesentium eum rerum illo dolore\nquasi exercitationem rerum nam\nporro quis neque quo\nconsequatur minus dolor quidem veritatis sunt non explicabo similique',
    },
    {
        userId: 6,
        id: 54,
        title: 'sit asperiores ipsam eveniet odio non quia',
        body: 'totam corporis dignissimos\nvitae dolorem ut occaecati accusamus\nex velit deserunt\net exercitationem vero incidunt corrupti mollitia',
    },
];
```

Below is my "UserList" component which pass in the resource component under Admin

```
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField } from 'react-admin';

export const UserList = () => (
    <List>
        <Datagrid rowClick='edit'>
            <TextField source='id' />
            <TextField source='name' />
            <TextField source='username' />
            <EmailField source='email' />
            <TextField source='address.street' />
            <TextField source='phone' />
            <TextField source='website' />
            <TextField source='company.name' />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Below is the error I am getting.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGL8F.png)

I tried providing dataProvider prop my dummy json data but it's showing an error which I have attached as an image. Can someone please tell me that how could I test my React-Admin with dummy json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ["FakeRest Data Provider For React-Admin"](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-fakerest) it doesn't require a server. List of available [Data Providers](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderList.html) for React-Admin.